# Additional files / directories to be monitored by Pyramid for autorestart

Tags: python, pyramid

Pyramid has a nifty feature of restarting automatically if some `.py` or `.ini` file in its app scope have changed.

I have some more files (they're not `.py` nor `.ini`) that I need watched — how do I add them to Pyramid monitoring?

Comment: Looks like `pserve` command internally has hook to add extra files, but I fail to see through the abstraction layers how one can poke it https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/blob/master/pyramid/scripts/pserve.py#L808

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You (and may be some day pyramid itself) might be better of with implementing the desired behaviour into a custom [watchdog](http://pythonhosted.org//watchdog/quickstart.html#quickstart) implementation. Just follow my thoughts...

Create a script that takes your PasteDeploy `.ini` file to run the `pserve` commands and installs a watchdog for the file extensions to monitor.

Watchdog event handler just changes modification time of your `.ini` file since this file is already monitored by pyramid watcher.

```
$ touch pyramid.ini
```

results in a reload:

```
pyramid.ini changed; reloading...
-------------------- Restarting --------------------
2015-04-29 08:51:05,216 INFO  [ZEO.ClientStorage] ('localhost', 8100) ClientStorage (pid=5263) created RW/normal for storage: '1'
2015-04-29 08:51:05,217 INFO  [ZEO.cache] created temporary cache file '<fdopen>'
2015-04-29 08:51:05,227 INFO  [ZEO.ClientStorage] ('localhost', 8100) Testing connection <ManagedClientConnection ('127.0.0.1', 8100)>
2015-04-29 08:51:05,228 INFO  [ZEO.zrpc.Connection('C')] (127.0.0.1:8100) received handshake 'Z3101'
2015-04-29 08:51:05,329 INFO  [ZEO.ClientStorage] ('localhost', 8100) Server authentication protocol None
2015-04-29 08:51:05,331 INFO  [ZEO.ClientStorage] ('localhost', 8100) Connected to storage: ('localhost', 8100)
2015-04-29 08:51:05,332 INFO  [ZEO.ClientStorage] ('localhost', 8100) No verification necessary -- empty cache
Starting server in PID 5263.
serving on http://0.0.0.0:6543
```

You could even import useful stuff from `pserve` module that fits your use case. Look at this [scripting approach](http://pythonhosted.org//watchdog/hacking.html#enabling-continuous-integration) to get an idea on how to drive a watchdog.